# How to get(access) foreign key's member instance in django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-serializer

1. articles/models.py

   ```
    class Article(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ```
2. user/models.py

   ```
    class User(AbstractUser):
       username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
       profile_image_url = models.TextField()
   ```

Is there any other way to include or access user's member instance (username, email, profile_image_url) into class Article??

I'd like to make class Article into this

```
 class Article(models.Model):
     User.username
     User.email
     User.profile_image_url
```

FYI,my Serializer are these

```
 class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
          model = Article
          fields = ['emotion', 'location', 'menu', 'weather', 'song', 'point', 'content', 'image', 'user', 'created', 'liked', 'num_liked']


 class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('id', 'username', 'date_joined', 'email', 'profile_image_url', 
          'followings', 'followers')
```

**Is there any other way to make my ArticleSerializer to include UserSerializer's fields?
or Is there any other way to include or access user's member instance (username, email, profile_image_url) into class Article??**

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email', allow_null=True)
    # And so on

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'email')
```

Comment: sorry but what do ou mean #And so on?

Comment: @TimoTomate I meant the other `user` fields to include them in the same way